# PHP - utf8_decode with special characters are in lower case

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue with encoding in PHP. I try to decode in UTF-8 a string with the function utf8_decode.

Unfortunately, when the special characters are in lower case, utf8_decode failed.

Example:

```
utf8_decode("moi-mÃªme"); // moi-même => it works fine.
```

But:

```
utf8_decode("moi-mãªme"); // failed : "moi-m�me"
```

I need to decode huge text. So, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: utf8_decode is to turn working utf8 into garbage iso8859. Is this what you are trying to achieve? Downgrading? I'm curious.

Comment: UTF8 encompasses virtually all alphabets for virtually all languages. ISO8859-1 barely encompasses a few western-european alphabets.

Comment: My main goal is not to use iso8859. I want just display this text correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [UTF-8 table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) you will see

> C3 AA => ê

Now if you look at [ISO-8859-1 table](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Emiles/iso8859.html) you will get

> C3 => Ã
>
> AA => ª

thats why Ãª (iso) => ê (utf8)

now if you look at ISO table for

> E3 => ã
>
> AA => ª

and there is no equivalent E3 AA in UTF-8 table, which means that `ãª` is invalid.

Comment: Ahh so the input is already [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got confused. PHP did his job just fine, you can check the actual value of the decoded character this way:

```
php > echo ord(utf8_decode("moi-mãªme")[5]);
227
```

and if you look at the symbol table of the iso-8859-1 encoding ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) you'll see that 227 (E3) is ã. The reason that you see "moi-m�me" is that your terminal character encoding is probably set to utf-8. And any number that is higher than 0x80 in UTF-8 means that it is multibyte character so in this case it will be [e3aa](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/58282/UTF-8-character).

To see correct output change your terminal character encoding to iso-8859-1.